# Notifications are not delivering xamarin android

Tags: c#, push-notification, xamarin.android, firebase-cloud-messaging

When the notification is recieved following code is handling the message:

```
private void SendNotification(string message)
{
    var intent = new Intent(this, typeof(MainActivity));
    intent.AddFlags(ActivityFlags.ClearTop);
    var pendingIntent = PendingIntent.GetActivity(this, 0, intent, PendingIntentFlags.OneShot);

    var notificationBuilder = new Notification.Builder(this)
            .SetContentTitle("GCM Message")
            .SetContentText(message)
            .SetAutoCancel(true)
            .SetContentIntent(pendingIntent);

     var notificationManager = (NotificationManager)GetSystemService(Context.NotificationService);
     notificationManager.Notify(0, notificationBuilder.Build());
}
```

But nothing shows. 
I'm debugging it it that would make any difference? 
When I go to settings on the app on the device, "Show notifications" is checked.

**Comment 1:**

```
using (var notificationManager = NotificationManager.FromContext(ApplicationContext))
{
    var title = "Title";
    var channelName = "TestChannel"
    if (Build.VERSION.SdkInt >= BuildVersionCodes.O)
    {
        NotificationChannel channel = null;
        if (channel == null)
        {
            channel = new NotificationChannel(channelName, channelName, NotificationImportance.Low)
            {
                LockscreenVisibility = NotificationVisibility.Public
            };
            channel.SetShowBadge(true);
            notificationManager.CreateNotificationChannel(channel);
        }
        channel.Dispose();
    }
    var bitMap = BitmapFactory.DecodeResource(Resources, Resource.Drawable.notification_template_icon_bg);
    var notificationBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(ApplicationContext)
                                                            .SetContentTitle(title)
                                                            .SetContentText(message)
                                                            .SetLargeIcon(bitMap)
                                                            .SetShowWhen(false)
                                                            .SetChannelId(channelName);

    var notification = notificationBuilder.Build();
    notificationManager.Notify(0, notification);
}
```

Runnig that code, no errors but nothing shows up.

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following this guid helped me:

https://learn.microsoft.com/sv-se/xamarin/android/app-fundamentals/notifications/local-notifications-walkthrough

I think the reason I didn't see any notifications was that I didn't have an icon. After adding an icon to the notification, everything worked.

**Result:**

```
[Service(Exported = false), IntentFilter(new[] { "com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" })]
public class GcmNotificationService : GcmListenerService
{
    //More information on how to set different things from notification can be found here
    //https://learn.microsoft.com/sv-se/xamarin/android/app-fundamentals/notifications/local-notifications

    public override void OnMessageReceived(string from, Bundle data)
    {
        var message = data.GetString("message");
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(message))
        {
            if (!NotificationContextHelper.Handle(message))
                SendNotification(message);
        }
    }

    private void SendNotification(string message)
    {
        var builder = new Notification.Builder(this)
                .SetContentTitle("Title")
                .SetContentText(message)
                .SetSmallIcon(Resource.Drawable.notification_test)
                .SetVisibility(NotificationVisibility.Public);

        var notification = builder.Build();
        var notificationManager = GetSystemService(Context.NotificationService) as NotificationManager;
        notificationManager.Notify(0, notification);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

With the newer Android APIs, they now require a notification channel (`NotificationChannel`) to be used. You can do fairly easily by using  `NotificationCompat` from the Android support library and only creating the channel if you are on Oreo or later.

#### NotificationCompat  w/ Channel Example:

```
using (var notificationManager = NotificationManager.FromContext(ApplicationContext))
{
    var channelName = GetText(Resource.String.notificationChannelNormal);
    if (Build.VERSION.SdkInt >= BuildVersionCodes.O)
    {
        NotificationChannel channel = null;
        #if !DEBUG
        channel = notificationManager.GetNotificationChannel(channelName);
        #endif
        if (channel == null || resetChannel)
        {
            channel = new NotificationChannel(channelName, channelName, NotificationImportance.Low)
            {
                LockscreenVisibility = NotificationVisibility.Public
            };
            channel.SetShowBadge(true);
            notificationManager.CreateNotificationChannel(channel);
        }
        channel.Dispose();
    }
    Bitmap bitMap = BitmapFactory.DecodeResource(Resources, Resource.Drawable.ic_launcher);
    var notificationBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(ApplicationContext)
                                                    .SetContentTitle(title)
                                                    .SetContentText(message)
                                                    .SetSmallIcon(Resource.Drawable.ic_stat_notification_network_locked)
                                                    .SetLargeIcon(bitMap)
                                                    .SetShowWhen(false)
                                                    .SetChannelId(channelName)
                                                    .SetContentIntent(pendingIntent);
    return notificationBuilder.Build();
}
```

Comment: @vmorin What comment?

Comment: See comment above @SushiHangover

Answer (score 0):

Important to note that in the AndroidManifest.xml the fully qualified class name is used eg: android:name = "com.companyname.myapp.MyFirebaseMessagingService"

**AND** the namespace for the service where the class is implemented should be com.companyname.myapp.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/33389618)