# Xamarin.Android Alarm Manager SetSound MP3-file

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, alarmmanager

I have `LocalNotificationService` And I am creating notification for Android there. How can I add custom sound named `Sound_04669` into `AlarmManager` instead `RingtoneManager.GetDefaultUri(RingtoneType.Alarm)`

My code of building notification:

```
//Generating notification       
        var builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(Application.Context)       
            .SetContentTitle(notification.Title)       
            .SetContentText(notification.Body)       
            .SetSmallIcon(notification.IconId)       
            .SetSound(RingtoneManager.GetDefaultUri(RingtoneType.Alarm))       
            .SetAutoCancel(true);
```

Thanks everyone!

Comment: Are you creating and setting the sound in a notification channel? (required for Oreo and above) as I do not see the channel in your `NotificationCompat.Builder`... (also I do not know which API level you are testing on)

Comment: No, what is it?

Comment: https://devblogs.microsoft.com/xamarin/android-oreo-notification-channels/

Comment: @SushiHangover https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/how-to-send-local-notification-with-repeat-interval-in-xamarin-forms/ i use this. How can I do notification channel with LocalNotificationService in App.Droid . Help me please!!!

Comment: NotificationCompat.Builder  has a SetChannelId method where you set the channel: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51254256/notifications-are-not-delivering-xamarin-android/51254587#51254587 So the code in your question should add the channel and move the setting of the sound to the channel code.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try this?

```
var alarmUri = Android.Net.Uri.Parse("MyApp.Android/Resources/raw/alarm.mp3");
```

here is full code

```
private void createNotificationChannel()
            {
                var channelName = GetString(Resource.String.noti_chan_urgent);
                var channelDescription = GetString(Resource.String.noti_chan_urgent_description);

                // set the vibration patterm for the channel
                long[] vibrationPattern = { 100, 200, 300, 400, 500, 400, 300, 200, 400 };

                // Creating an Audio Attribute
               var alarmAttributes = new AudioAttributes.Builder()
                                      .SetContentType(AudioContentType.Sonification)
                                      .SetUsage(AudioUsageKind.Alarm)
                                      .Build();

                // Create the uri for the alarm file
                // Note: Make sure you add the mp3 file in your Android project under Resources/raw/soundFile.mp3 and set the build as Android Resource
                var alarmUri = Android.Net.Uri.Parse("MyApp.Android/Resources/raw/alarm.mp3");   


                // create chan1  which is the urgent notifications channel
                var chan1 = new NotificationChannel(PRIMARY_CHANNEL_ID, channelName, NotificationImportance.High)
                {
                    Description = channelDescription
                };


                // set the channel properties
                chan1.EnableLights(true);
                chan1.LightColor = Color.Red;
                chan1.EnableVibration(true);   
                chan1.SetVibrationPattern(vibrationPattern);
                chan1.SetSound(alarmUri, alarmAttributes);          // this is where the sound is set for the channel
                chan1.SetBypassDnd(true);
                chan1.LockscreenVisibility = NotificationVisibility.Public;

                // finally create the channel
                var manager = (NotificationManager)GetSystemService(NotificationService);
                manager.CreateNotificationChannel(chan1);
            }

        }
```

Comment: var manager = (NotificationManager)GetSystemService(NotificationService); shows error